# Unable to make Spring 3 Session Concurency Control work

Tags: session, configuration, spring-security

Using Spring Security 3.1.0, I cannot seem to get the concurrent session control feature to work. When I log into my system at the same time using IE and FireFox (using my local workstation) I see my user principle in the session registry twice. I am expecting the concurrent session control to log me out or throw an exception or do something that indicates I am logged into the site more than once and it is not permitted.

For what it's worth, I could not get the concurrency control to work at all using the auto config of the HTTP namespace element, even with specifying that my site uses a custom login form. I'm wondering if that might be due to the fact that my authentication is provided via LDAP...?

Here's my security config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

 <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
     <custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrencyFilter" />
     <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="myAuthFilter"/>
     <session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas"/>
  <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/css/**" access="permitAll" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/js/**" access="permitAll" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="permitAll" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/home/**" access="permitAll" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/admin/user/**" access="hasRole('AUTH_MANAGE_USERS')" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/admin/group/**" access="hasRole('AUTH_MANAGE_USERS')" />
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
  <access-denied-handler error-page="/403.html"/>
  <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/public/home.do"/>
 </http>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
          class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/public/login.do"/>
        <beans:property name="forceHttps" value="false"/>
    </beans:bean>

  <beans:bean id="concurrencyFilter"
       class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter">
     <beans:property name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
     <beans:property name="expiredUrl" value="/expired.html" />
   </beans:bean>

   <beans:bean id="myAuthFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
     <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas" />
     <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
   </beans:bean>

   <beans:bean id="sas" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy">
     <beans:constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry" />
     <beans:property name="maximumSessions" value="1" />
     <beans:property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true"/>
   </beans:bean>

 <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <authentication-provider ref='ldapProvider' />
  <authentication-provider ref="externalUserLdapProvider"/>
 </authentication-manager>

 <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

 <beans:bean id="securityContext" 
  class="org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder" factory-method="getContext"/>

 <beans:bean id="ldapProvider"
  class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
  <beans:constructor-arg ref="bindAuthenticator" />
  <beans:constructor-arg ref="userService" />
  <beans:property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="permissionedUserContextMapper" />
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="permissionedUserContextMapper"
  class="...service.impl.PermissionedUserContextMapperImpl" >
  <beans:property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
 </beans:bean>  

 <!-- LDAP via AD-->
 <beans:bean id="bindAuthenticator"
  class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
  <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
  <beans:property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch" />
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="userSearch"
  class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
  <beans:constructor-arg>
   <beans:value></beans:value>
  </beans:constructor-arg>
  <beans:constructor-arg>
   <beans:value>(sAMAccountName={0})</beans:value>
  </beans:constructor-arg>
  <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
  <beans:property name="searchSubtree">
   <beans:value>true</beans:value>
  </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="contextSource"
  class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
  <beans:constructor-arg
   value="ldap://omitted" />
  <beans:property name="userDn"
   value="ommitted" />
  <beans:property name="password" value="omitted" />
 </beans:bean>

 <!--  Second LDAP Authenticator (Apache DS) -->
    <beans:bean id="externalUserLdapProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="externalUserBindAuthenticator"/>
  <beans:constructor-arg ref="userService" />
  <beans:property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="permissionedUserContextMapper" />
    </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="externalUserBindAuthenticator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
  <beans:constructor-arg ref="externalUserContextSource" />
  <beans:property name="userDnPatterns">
   <beans:list>
    <beans:value>cn={0},ou=Users</beans:value>
   </beans:list>
  </beans:property>
 </beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="externalUserContextSource" 
   class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
     <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://omitted"/>
 </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Am I missing some property that should tell the concurrency control strategy to barf if the user logs more than 1 session? I know the same user is logging more than one session -- as I am seeing duplicate principles in the session registry.

Any/all replies are very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SessionRegistry` uses `equals()`/`hashCode()` of `UserDetails` to find sessions of the same user. If you have custom `UserDetails`, perhaps it's not implemented.

Comment: That was absolutely the problem. Bonehead me. Thank you so very much!